# sorting PointF array

Tags: c#, sorting

Could anyone help me with creating an algoritm, IComparer, or some method that would sort an array or list of `PointF` elements. Lets say I got following `PointF` elements in my array:

- [0] {**X** = 50.0 **Y** = 0.0}
- [1] {**X** = 100.0 **Y** = 100.0}
- [2] {**X** = 0.0 **Y** = 100.0}
- [3] {**X** = 100.0 **Y** = 0.0}
- [4] {**X** = 0.0 **Y** = 0.0}
- [5] {**X** = 100.0 **Y** = 50.0}
- [6] {**X** = 50.0 **Y** = 100.0}

What I would want to achieve is:

- first are elements with lowest **Y** and **X**
- still elements with lowest **Y** but **X** would get bigger
- then as the highest possible **X** at this lowest **Y** get achieved it would go, all elements with this **X**, but with bigger and bigger **Y**
- as the top **Y** and top **X** get achieved, it would go from elements with top **X** and top **Y**, to elements still with top **Y**, but with lower and lower **X**

So this sorted array would look something like this:

- [4] {**X** = 0.0 **Y** = 0.0}
- [0] {**X** = 50.0 **Y** = 0.0}
- [3] {**X** = 100.0 **Y** = 0.0}
- [5] {**X** = 100.0 **Y** = 50.0}
- [1] {**X** = 100.0 **Y** = 100.0}
- [6] {**X** = 50.0 **Y** = 100.0}
- [2] {**X** = 0.0 **Y** = 100.0}

Meaning, that at the end, if I were to draw these points using `Graphics.DrawPolygon()` I would get a closed polygon(in this case a rectangle) with no lines crossing each other.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Smells like homework?

Comment: `IComparer` isn't going to work as it determines if one item is less than, equal to, or greater than another item without knowledge of any other items.

Comment: So, you want to arrange some points into a closed polygon, its over simplistic to think of that as sorting.

Comment: No its not a homework, I am working on a project for my self. I have tried creating some methods with loops, but I just cant think of a way to get this to work...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path

Comment: @Jodrell: I think the poster wants the convex hull, not a Hamiltonian.

Comment: Does the polygon need to cross every point or just contain every point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm you want is the Graham Scan. You can read about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan

juharr's comment is correct; you're not going to be able to do this with `IComparable` because *this is not a comparison sort problem*. For a comparison sort to work, you need to be able to compare any two elements for relative size.

An easier-but-slower algorithm is the gift wrapping algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

FYI the shape you are looking for is called the *convex hull*. That will help you when searching for algorithms.

Comment: Yes, this seems like the thing I am looking for. But I am not that very goot at english, especially not in mathematics written in english. And since there is no translation to my language. Could you do a quick summary of the article? Please...

Comment: Well since I would produce a summary in mathematical English, that wouldn't help you very much. Perhaps you can find information about convex hull algorithms in your native language.

Comment: I guess you're right, I will just have to read this thru untill I understand enough, to create some sort of method that would do this.